# Why is this div not the same height as the input? (In Firefox)

Tags: html, css

I've created a div and input and given both exactly the same borders, padding, margins, fonts and font-sizes. But they're still not the same height. Why?

**Edit: Using Firefox**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a8n6qxaz/

HTML:

```
<div class="close">X</div>
<input type="submit" value="TEST" />
```

CSS:

```
    input[type="submit"]
    {
      position: relative;
      margin-right: .5em;
      float: right;
      margin: 0em;
      padding: 0.125em;
      padding-left: .25em;
      padding-right: .25em;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
      font-size: 1.25em;
      line-height: 1em;
      color: #ffffff;
      appearance: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-radius: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: red;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .close
    {
      position: relative;
      margin-right: .5em;
      float: right;
      margin: 0em;
      padding: 0.125em;
      padding-left: .25em;
      padding-right: .25em;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
      font-size: 1.25em;
      line-height: 1em;
      color: red;
      appearance: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-radius: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: #3e3f39;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: On which browser? They're the same height for me in your fiddle (using Chrome).

Comment: @jperezov Firefox. Just checked and you're correct in Chrome they're the same!

Comment: Why don't you use `height`? When setting that attribute, I get both elements with the same height. I am testing it with Firefox as well.

Comment: @Nicolás Giving them the same height in Firefox still gives different sizes.

Comment: @DonRhummy, they have the same height in my browser. May be you can put input field in div and control the div through css

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't specify any height, so use e.g.

```css
height: 1em;
```

However, by default the height of the input is considered using the border-box model, and the height of the div using the content-box model. Use the `box-sizing` property to specify the same model for both elements:

```css
box-sizing: content-box;
```

```css
input[type="submit"], .close {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: .5em;
  float: right;
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0.125em;
  padding-left: .25em;
  padding-right: .25em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1em;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="close">TEST</div>
<input type="submit" value="TEST" />
```

Comment: But it doesn't explain why if they both have height & no border & all css the same the height is still not the same? It looks like firefox bug. Unless there is some other css in play which is not the same by default

Comment: @jonasnas Yes, it's because the sizing models are different by default. They don't have borders but they have paddings, so when you set an explicit height, one will include the padding and the other won't.

Comment: @Oriol You'll notice your example has them not exactly aligned vertically (the text). They're 1 pixel off in Firefox

Comment: @DonRhummy [It works OK for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WeaQb.png). In fact that would be a violation of the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules), because floats must be placed as high as possible.

Comment: @Oriol Run your code snippet and you'll see, the second "Test" is 1 pixel higher. (You may have to screenshot it, open it in GIMP or Photoshop and zoom in)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, in Firefox, padding is applied differently in an input than a div **even if they're both `display: block` and you remove the `appearance` of the input**. `line-height` also messes up in an input.

Removing the top/bottom padding from both and line-height from the input, allows making them the same height:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8n6qxaz/4/

```
    input[type="submit"]
    {
      position: relative;
      margin-right: .5em;
      float: right;
      margin: 0em;
      height: 1.5em;
      padding: 0em;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
      font-size: 1.25em;
      color: #ffffff;
      appearance: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-radius: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: red;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .close
    {
      position: relative;
      margin-right: .5em;
      float: right;
      margin: 0em;
      height: 1.5em;
      padding: 0em;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
      font-size: 1.25em;
      line-height: 1.5em;
      color: #ffffff;
      appearance: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-radius: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: red;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't specify the `height`, and firefox applies different default `height` for `div` and for `input` than chrome

Comment: See my answer. Setting the height isn't enough. You need to **also** remove the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` or Firefox still shows them as different heights.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the `input` to behave like the `div`, you must change the box-model of the `input`:

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

Add that CSS property to the `input`, and then in firefox both `div` and `input` will consider the `padding` in the same manner.